# How can I get command-line arguments passed to a SLURM job from its job ID?

Tags: slurm

Suppose I'm running a SLURM job with command-line arguments, let's say `srun sleep 1000`. `squeue` and `scontrol show job ID` show the executed command `sleep`, but not its argument `1000`.

My question is, how can I get the arguments passed to a SLURM job command (`1000` in this example), from its job ID?

I'm using slurm 17.02.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the arguments of your command are not available in the *sinfo* information you could try to retrieve that data with the following procedure:

1. Export the command name and its arguments to an environment variable:

   `export JOBNAME="sleep 1000"`
2. Launch the job defining the job name and the executable:

   `srun -J"$JOBNAME" $JOBNAME &`
3. Retrieve information of that job from *sinfo* and select the appropriate data, in your case:

   `scontrol show jobid=your_job_id | grep JobName | cut -f3 -d" "`